# Creating new app and need assistance with Generating Signed Bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I selected 'Build' --> Generate Signed Bundle or APK

I choose Android App Bundle and click next

Here is see my Module which lists my app name

Then there is a Key Store path which is blank?! What do I do here? Do I hit the "Create New..." button to create a new key since its the first time building my app?

The other textsboxes are
Key store password which I would image i provide on the new key store path, if i need to create new key store

then there is Key alias, which I have no clue on  and key password.

Why is this sooooo complicated?

Can someone help me understand how I can just create a new android app bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the key first, when creating the key you'll set the alias and the password, here's the documentation detailing the process:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key